# Symbol cache map is 120MB - what is it and what does it contain?

Tags: java, gwt, deobfuscation

We have a GWT module in our project. Recently there was a major memory overload, and one of the things was a 120MB object stored in [StackTraceDeobfuscator.java](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/src/com/google/gwt/core/server/StackTraceDeobfuscator.java)  `ConcurrentHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> symbolMaps` field. What is it and what is it for?

At the moment of "the overload", out of 16 segments the map contained, 1st was 59MB, 2nd was 30MB and the 3rd was 29.9MB .

As far as I understand, it has to do with the fact that the code gets obfuscated and with storing stacktraces, but could someone please explain in more detail? Is it like, there were too many exceptions with huge stacktraces and they all got cached in? but 120MB is still huge, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GWT will try to produce a minimal JavaScript code in order to have smaller download and faster JavaScript interpretation on the client side. This includes shortening your identifiers used in the Java source to the possible shortest ones. Obviously the generated short identifier names are not very useful to you (to humans).

If any errors occur, this would mean error messages and stack traces would contain no useful information to you. To that end *resymbolizitaion* has been imlemented. *Symbol maps* are generated by the GWT compiler (at compile time) if the `-extra` compiler argument is provided. This symbol map contains mappings from the generated short identifiers to the original Java identifiers, so in case of errors the original names can be reproduced (simply looked up from the symbol map).

You can read more about this here: [**Resymbolization / Deobfuscation**](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions#Resymbolization_/_Deobfuscation)

Comment: Okay, so what was that "heavy" info weighting 120MB?

Comment: The symbol map contains mappings generated not just from your source code but also from code that is used from the GWT library. And also most likely for code compiled for multiple browsers.

Comment: And from that, it is normal that it takes so much memory?

Comment: It obviously depends on the size of your application and on what parts of the GWT lib you use. To me it looks a little much, but bear in mind that this symbol map is only needed for development, in production this doesn't have to be generated and loaded.

Comment: But it actually WAS noticed in production, do I just remove the -extra compiler argument?

Comment: "Symbol maps can be generated at compile time using the -extra GWT compiler argument, e.g. **-extra war/WEB-INF/classes/** "

but where do I look if it was specified or not?

Comment: Symbol map might be generated even if you don't specify the `-extra` parameter explicitly. This depends on the environment you use. For example if you use Eclipse and the Google Plugin to compile your GWT project, symbol maps are generated by default.

Comment: Do you know of a way to avoid that?

Comment: I'm not able to try it now, but I believe you can specify a folder after the `-extra` parameter which will be used to put extra (generated) files which are not intended for deployment. Just don't deploy the folder you specify or simply delete it.

Comment: Smart, I like it, will try. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use symbol maps in production deployment.
*symbolMaps* directory is excluded during war compilation 
`<exclude name="WEB-INF/deploy/**" />`. But recently I've tested deofuscation for remote logging functionality provided by [gwt-log](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted#Enable_the_remote_logging_option_(disabled_by_default)).

Symbol maps may be generated by `-deploy "path"` compilation flag.
Be careful this flag is ignored if you use `<collapse-all-properties />` in **gwt.xml**.